# How to make drop down menu stay open while hovering

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

When I am click in the about menu the drop down is not staying open as soon as I stop hoverig on the about menu it disappears. How to make it stay open ?

CSS

```
#nav-line2 .subMenu{
position:absolute;
z-index:999;
list-style:none;
display:none;
padding-left:441px;
}

#about:hover  + .subMenu , .subMenu:hover {display:block;}
```

HTML

```
    <div id="nav-line2" style="float:left">
    <a class="navlink" href="/whatwedo">what we do</a>
    <a class="navlink"   href="/communities">communities</a>
    <a class="navlink"  href="/catalog">gift catalog</a>
    <a class="navlink" href="/studentprofiles">student profiles</a>
    <a class="navlink" id="about" href="/aboutme">about</a>
<div class="subMenu">
    <li><a class="navlink" href="/about">Board of Directors</a></li>
    <li><a class="navlink" href="/accesgovernance">Structure & Governance</a></li>
    </div>
    <a class="navlink" href="/termsconditions" style="padding-left:10px">terms &amp; conditions</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You HTML is invalid. `li` must be children of a `ul`

Comment: Take a look at #id ul li:hover ul li:hover  and also the css selector >

Comment: you need to use jquery to toggle it, the css :hover will only work on hover

Comment: @gardni i think he meant that he cannot click the submenu because as soon as he stops hovering the parent menu, the submenu vanishes

Answer (score 1):

here is how you do it: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/jsXJU/)

3 things to notice:

1) `<li>` is supposed to be an element of `<ul>` and not `<div>`

2) easiest way to align the submenu to the relevant parent menu is to make him a direct child of that parent menu, and set parent position to `relative` and child's to `absolute`, that way when you set child `left` to `0` it will alight perfectly.

3) easiest way to make a menu bar is by using a user list `<ul>` and setting its list items' display to `inline` to make it horizontal.